# Ion-datetime angular- I want to display time in following range 7 AM - 10 PM

Tags: angular, date, ionic-framework, time

I have a restriction in my Angular-Ionic app that user can not select time before 7 AM and after 12 PM. I want to show him time from 7AM to 10PM only but also want to show AM/PM options.

The problem I am facing is that if user select 11 in hours and changes AM to PM than my condition is violated so how can user strictly restricted between 7am to 10pm that if user selects 11 in hours than he cant change am to pm.

Following is my code:

```html
<ion-label position="floating">Start Time</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime type="text" displayFormat="hh:mm a" minuteValues="0,15,30,45" min="07:00" max="22:00" [(ngModel)]="slot.startTime" name="start">
</ion-datetime>
```

Visual example:
[image]

Comment: kindly click enter image description here to see image

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the ion-picker (pickerController) :
https://ionicv5-pickerwrestriction.stackblitz.io
In my example, if 01h and "PM" are selected at the same time, the validate button is disabled and the color and text change.
I didn't manage to dynamically change the column content or prevent from selecting PM when 01 is already selected.

Note :It might be possible with ion-datetime but more difficult as you need to catch the ion-picker when it displays.